# Align popup in Kendo UI grid cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to put a template for a column which will have a dropdown kind of element(Do note, it is not a dropdown. If it so, I would have used Kendo dropdown).

The column template is some thing like this:

```
  template:function(rec) {
    var str = '<div style="background:red;position:relative;">'
        + rec.Country +
        '<div style="width:100%;position:absolute;top:10px;left:0px;z-index:9999;background-color:green;display:inline-block;">' +
        '<ul>' +
            '<li>Mexico</li>' +
            '<li>Germany</li>' +
            '<li>UK</li>' +
            '<li>Spain</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>'
    '</div>';
    return str;
}
```

There are two `div` tags where the first one is positioned `relative`, and child `div` is positioned `absolute` to parent `div`.
Here, the problem is child `div` list is being hidden inside the `TD` tag of the Kendo-UI grid though `z-index` is set to some max value.

But the same piece of code is working fine in normal plain html table.The problem is with Kendo Grid only.

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/herikozoki/1/edit?html,output) of kendo grid example and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fapopuloce/1/) of plain html table.

Comment: i think it is the overflow of the TD hide your div, if you add overflow : visible to the TD of the kendo ui grid the problem is gone

Comment: @machun Yeah, now TD part is resolved.but if dropdown of last row is opened, that is being hidden tbody/table. Table is getting scroll instead of the popup is shown on top of the table.